# Application becomes completely unclickable/uninteractable sometimes

Tags: windows, freeze

I started using a new laptop (thinkpad T14 with Ryzen CPU) last week.
There is one application(in this case, SAP Business One) that sometimes would become completely unclickable. Let me try to explain the "unclickable" with the following symptoms:

- clicking on anywhere on the window does absolutely nothing. As if the window has been covered by glass, and all the clicks did not reach the window at all. Or as if the left button on the mouse is not functioning at all.
- if I place another small window on top of it, clicking on it does not bring it to the foreground. Only way to bring it forward is to use taskbar icon.
- the application appears to be normal state. (not "not responding" or anything)
- the "minimize", "maximize", "close" buttons don't even work.
- when trying to kill the application with task manager, I can see the application pops up a window asking "are you sure you want to quit". I understand this as the application is in normal state (not "not responding").

Is this the application's fault? or is it the operating systems' fault? any tips on troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: new laptop (thinkpad T14 .....    Uninstall the SAP App, restart and reinstall the app. Test.  If you still have issues call SAP Support first and then call Lenovo Support second if SAP says their app is OK

Comment: With freezing applications, it’s are almost always the application itself that is at fault. As long as it’s still processing window messages, Windows will not mark it as hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have encountered similar behavior with applications when Windows fails to display a pop-up dialog. That is, either the application itself generates a general pop-up, which is hidden by the main UI window, or generates a Windows UAC prompt that is otherwise hidden for some reason.

I might suggest using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through open desktop windows the next time this occurs, to see if either of these situations apply. If so, closing or cancelling the pop-up should (ideally) help to resolve this issue (i.e. make the main application window responsive again).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's actually one of the first things that came to mind, but that's probably not it in my case.  I'll try to get the vendor of the software, in this case SAP, to help with this issue.